# Javascript within a user control in an UpdatePanel not running

Tags: asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0, webforms

I have a webform which contains some LinkButtons.
When each LinkButton is clicked I want to load a different UserControl.
I also want to do it with Ajax.

I tried it in two ways as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072091/1083652) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10931323/1083652)
[Both approaches use an UpdatePanel, the first adds the user control and changes its `Visible` attribute, the second uses `LoadControl` function]

Both works (upvoted them!) but I still have a problem-
I can't run javascripts within the user controls...
It doesn't recognize any function

When the user controls were added *not dynamically* it all went well

The only workaround I found was to move the javascript from the user control to the page but that's not nice...

Also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4416711/1083652) with no luck

Any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For asynchronous requests use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` method

Comment: Damn! I was so close when I was looking at http://stackoverflow.com/a/4416711/1083652 ... Anyway, your answer works - thanks!